# Concourse trigger from 2 weeks after the previous job is done

Tags: git, concourse

I need to create a trigger that will execute a task 2 weeks after it has been called.

This is for a git merge where I merge a branch into master using the concourse pipeline and then want concourse to automatically delete the branch 2 weeks after the merge.

Is there a way to do this using the timer resource?

Comment: Really interested in this use case. Is there something else, other than time, that you can trigger that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

No. The time resource works on an interval, it is not a one time trigger in the way you are looking for.